# How to Remove float:right; from a MySQL table column?

Tags: mysql, bluehost

I need to write a query that will delete this string float:right; from inside a column called description.

This database is in BlueHost and no mater what query I try, Bluehost is giving me this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'field like
 '% float:right%' at line 1
```

This is the last query I tried:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE `description` field like '% float:right%'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Zelldon for editing the questions.  I was worried about how awful it looked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to `delete`.  That deletes rows.  You want to update:

```
update tablename
    set description = replace(description, 'float:right;', '')
    where description like '% float:right;%';
```

If you want to delete all rows that match that pattern, then your original query is pretty close:

```
delete from tablename
    where description like '% float:right%';
```

To see what rows would be affected by either query, use:

```
select *
from tablename
where description like '% float:right%';
```

Comment: I just want to delete that phrase from inside ALL my records on the column description.  I have over 600 descriptions of products on this table.

Comment: If you want to keep the rows but change the description, the first query works.

Comment: I don't get an error.  It just says 0 rows affected and the string is still there.

Comment: @user1667057 . . . Do a `select` to find the rows that would be affected.  Perhaps it is the space at the beginning of the string (which is in the original posting).

Comment: Ok, I got it to work with your querry.  But the string that I need to delete has a semicolon at the end like this float:right;  When I take the semicolon out it works.  How do I write the query to also remove that semicolon?

Comment: @user1667057 . . . You add it into the second argument of the `replace()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add it to the second argument.  I'm not a developer or programmer.  I'm afraid it will delete all the semicolons on my description column.

Comment: I got it to work with the first query with this '% float:right;%'  It was not working before because I had an extra space on the string I wanted to remove.  Thanks Gordon Linoff!!!!!  I would have upvoted but I'm not allowed yet.